# create relationship based on weights in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

trying to create a relationship using the query mentioned below. its showing **syntax error** if i use "sum" or a "+" the value for flavour and locperorg are integers

```
MATCH (m:Dish_name), (n:Dish_name)      
WHERE NOT (m)=(n) AND m.locperorg = n.locperorg
and not m.locperorg = 0
create (m)-[:Relation{wt{m.locperorg+n.locperorg}}]-(n)


MATCH (m:Dish_name),(n:Dish_name)
WHERE NOT (m)=(n) AND m.flavour = n.flavour and not m.flavour = 0
create (m)-[:Relation1{wt: {sum ( m.flavour,n.flavour )}}]->(n);
```

After updating the query trying to create a relationship using the query mentioned below. its showing Java heap space and Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownFailure

```
MATCH (m:Dish_name)
WHERE NOT m.time = 0
WITH m
MATCH (n:Dish_name {time: m.time})      
WHERE m <> n
CREATE (m)-[:Relation{wt:m.time+n.time}]->(n)
```

Comment: Hey @veda did you say that the query ran fine once and then not a second time? I think that you may need to open a new question detailing the size of your graph, the running environment (console/embedded/rest) and the system configuration.

Comment: @JohnMark13 since i am new at stackoverflow i am not able to post many questions thus i am dragging it here only. the query did not run fine even once. the running environment is "console". the graph has 1000 nodes (Dishes) having 16 numeric properties each. i am trying to build a relation between them wherein the weight of the relationship is equal to the sum of common properties (parameters) between nodes. hope you could comprehend what i am saying.

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum, we can maybe go to chat, but if you change the `CREATE ...` to a `RETURN m, n` do you get any results?

Comment: Yes it does. i have created nodes and can see them aswell. It would be great if you could add me on hangout ( vedansh13@gmail.com ). Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested.. Firstly your query could be quite slow, I would match the non 0 Dishes first and then the equal `n` Dishes. This avoids the cartesian product. And the error is because you have a slight mistake in the syntax, with the second brace, which should be a colon.

```
MATCH (m:Dish_name)
WHERE NOT m.locperorg = 0
WITH m
MATCH (n:Dish_name {locperorg: m.locperorg})      
WHERE m <> n
CREATE (m)-[:Relation{wt:m.locperorg+n.locperorg}]->(n)
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply. I tried the above query worked with just one alteration. the relation was not symmetrical. i had to give it a direction towards (n). any idea why so?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Neo4J does not support undirected relationships, so it needs to be created with a direction. You can then query without a direction. If you need to represent a relationship in both directions, create two relationships, one pointing each way. Both approaches will have an impact on how you traverse the graph.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you again but i tried running the same however after some time it just stops executing the query and when I recheck, the relationship it does not exist.

Comment: Can you update your query with what you are using and how it is hanging?

Comment: Sorry did not realise what you meant by updating the query. Will take care of that now onwards. anyidea why is the query not able to create relations?